# assign modified vector without changing the original vector R

Tags: r, vector

Let's say I have a vector `x<-c(a=2,b=3,c=5)`. I want to create a new vector `y` based on `x` s.t. `y` is `c(a=2,b=3,c=4)`. I know I can write:

```
y<-x
y['c']<-4
```

but is there a way I can do this in one step in R? I have to do this multiple times so writing it out each time wastes a lot of lines.

Comment: `y <- replace(x, "c", 4)`

Comment: Note that `replace` is literally the following: `function(x, list, values) { x[list] = values; x}`